# How to use useState to declare an array of strings, and then update it when using Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following

```
interface ISTx {
    tx: Array<string>,
    setTx: any
}

const [tx, setTx]  = useState<ISTx>([]) //Argument of type 'never[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ISTx

setTx(oldArr  => [...oldArr , txHash]) //Argument of type '(oldArr: ISTx) => any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<ISTx>
```

But im receiving the errors that are commented in the blockcode above.

Im basically trying to create a state that is an array of strings, and push new strings into it.

Comment: Your default vote doesn't actually match the interface, what did you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const [tx, setTx] = useState<string[]>([]);
```

You declare the type of your state between the angled brackets (<>). React will provide the necessary types for `tx` and `setTx`.